# getting awk to filter endless pipes

Tags: awk, pipe

with "cat /dev/tty0" I can read a continuous stream of input characters. Some incoming "telegrams" are delimited by a new-line character.
No I want to filter this by awk, but I can't figure out how to start awk doing analysis. It seems it always waits for an end of file, I see no outcome on stdout

So this works, showing my the first word of each line:

```
cat /dev/tty0 > myfile  (cancel somtime with Ctrl-C)
cat myfile | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}'
```

But this not, showling nothing:

```
cat /dev/tty0 | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}'
```

any ideas?
  Achim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `tail -f`.

```
tail -f /dev/tty0 | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}'
```

`tail` has other options which may be of use such as `--pid=nnn` which stops the `tail` when a given process dies.  Big `-F` may also work, depending on your flavour.

Comment: BTW, you probably won't be able to run this in the background if the tty is your own terminal.

Answer (score 3):

This may be due to buffering. I can't seem to reproduce your results, but try this (stdbuf is part of coreutils):

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 cat /dev/tty0 | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}'
```

Or this (unbuffer is part of expect):

```
unbuffer cat /dev/tty0 | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}'
```

Or this:

```
awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}' < /dev/tty0
```

Comment: But I still have some basic lack of knowledge in Linux pipes :-( In my question I suppressed a small detail: The telegrams are received on tty0 binary format with 24 bytes, so to convert them to ASCII I used " | od -w24 -An -tu1 " between the stdbuf/cat and awk, but than it will again not work.... :-(

Comment: I've got it, simply use stdbuf twice:  "*stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 cat /dev/tty0 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 od -w24 -An -tu1 | awk '{printf "Temp: %s\n",$1}'*"